# Is there any way to control photoshop properties externally?

Tags: c++, c, photoshop

I am writing a small application to change the color of photoshop's brush. In photoshop, you have to go to the color picker and change the RGB value or pick a new color manually. I was wondering if there was a way to send a value to the variable/memory address that is holding that value.

I also wrote a application to change brush size from an external program, but it had to be done very crudely. The only solution I found was to send actual keystrokes of "[" and "]" which are hotkeys for brush size up and brush size down. Since there are no hotkeys to change the color, this method can't work. (I wrote this program in python but I am trying to find a c/c++ solution for the color problem)

Ideas would be great :)

Comment: Speaking of crude solutions, you can check which messages are sent when you select a colour and try to work with that.

Comment: Hi chris, what do you mean checking which messages are sent?

Comment: I think Spy++ can do that. When you select something, there's most likely a specific message being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop exposes it's COM interface so you should be able to access these properties through that using c#, c++, etc.

Try these:

[Accessing COM interface from C or C++ in Windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410005/accessing-com-interface-from-c-or-c-in-windows-environment)

[Accessing an application's COM interface using C++ or C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410184/accessing-an-applications-com-interface-using-c-or-c)

Or for osx:

http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html

Comment: Thanks, I never looked into COM before and it seems to do the trick. But I think COM is Windows only. Is there anything like this for OSX and other other operating systems in general?

Comment: I think there is an equivalent for osx but dont know what its called. This maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633302/what-is-the-equivalent-of-com-in-mac-os